# Calculate number based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the following solution to generate a number based on user input into two form fields http://jsfiddle.net/A3qat/5/

```
$("#download, #contention").keyup( function(){
  var n1 = $("#download").val();
  var n2 = $("#contention").val();

  var result = n1/n2;
  $("#label").text(result);
});
```

So, `n1/n2 = n3`

How can I modify this to show the output (`n3`) in a separate input form field underneath rather than plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A3qat/49/

You should use `.val()`

```
   $("#field1, #field2").keyup( function(){

         var n1 = $("#field1").val();
         var n2 = $("#field2").val();

           var result = n2/n1;
           $("#label").val(result);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `label` with `input` and replace `$("#label").text(result);` with `$("#label").val(result);`

```
    <input type="number" id="field1">
    <input type="number" id="field2">
    <input id="result"></input>

<script>
    $("#download, #contention").keyup( function(){
      var n1 = $("#download").val();
      var n2 = $("#contention").val();

      var result = n1/n2;
      $("#result").val(result);
    });
</script>
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/A3qat/51/

Answer (score 0):

If you  textbox, then you can get the value of the textbox or you can set the value of the textbox using `.val()`

On your

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="field1">
<input type="number" id="field2">

<span><input  type="text" id="label" ></span>
```

**JS**

```
   $("#field1, #field2").keyup( function(){

         var n1 = $("#field1").val();
         var n2 = $("#field2").val();

           var result = n2/n1;
           $("#label").val(result);


    });
```